# Http Post request giving null in Android Async Task?

Tags: android, apache, http, http-post

The post method for API is not working. The NewTask.execute() is giving error of "cannot resolve the symbol". If i remove this NewTask.execute(), API returns nothing.

makePostRequestAsyncTask NewTask= new makePostRequestAsyncTask();
NewTask.execute();

I have two question:

1. Why it is giving cannot resolve symbol error?
2. Why it is not returning anything when NewTask.execute() is removed?

p.s: Am I using Async Task correctly? Since I am a beginner so cannot be sure about it. Thanks.

```
    public void makePostRequest()
{
    class makePostRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost =

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //making POST request.
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                String response_body = reader.readLine();
                Log.d("Http Post Response:", String.valueOf(response));
              //  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                // write response to log

              //  Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        makePostRequestAsyncTask NewTask= new makePostRequestAsyncTask();
        NewTask.execute();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing and executing inside your `AsyncTask`.

```
   }
    makePostRequestAsyncTask NewTask= new makePostRequestAsyncTask();
    NewTask.execute();
}// AsyncTask your class close here
```

do instead means after closer of AsyncTask

```
    }
}// AsyncTask your class close here
makePostRequestAsyncTask NewTask= new makePostRequestAsyncTask();
    NewTask.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It worked. However now the code is giving an error
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference"
Any idea about this....why its returning NULL from Background method?

Comment: And what actually it is? As i mentioned I am a beginner so not aware of much terminologies as well. How to solve this one?

Comment: search google.!! read [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.Vi3ONrcrKHs) and post full error log

Comment: Did. Google just identified the occur, not the cure or reason.

Comment: you are returning null in `doInBackground`. whatever you return from `doInBackground` is catch by `onPostExecute`

Comment: What does that suggests? My API call isn't valid or the server isn't returning anything?